# Bootstrap: Change text of small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following issue with Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery:

I have a title, in `h1`, and a subtitle, in `small`. I want to change the text of both, using jQuery. My code is the following:

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id='h1id'>
    Hello World
    <br>
    <small id='smallid'>Here I am!</small>
</h1>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#h1id').text('I can change this');
    $('#smallid').text('But not this');

});
```

The `h1` is changed, but the `small`-element disappears. How can I fix this?

Live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nkzbzm7f/)

Comment: Its because your #h1id contains the #smallid, so when you change the content of the #h1id element, you delete the #smallid. ;)

Comment: For more details, Once you change `#h1id` then right click and view `Inspect element`. Now its overrided by your text `I can change this`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap hello world in a span

HTML

```
<h1 id='h1id'>
    <span>Hello World</span>
    <br>
    <small>Here I am!</small>
</h1>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#h1id span').text('I can change this');
    $('#h1id small').text('But not this');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another div or span like this :

```
<h1 id='h1id'>
    <div id="something">
        Hello World
    </div>
    <br>
    <small id='smallid'>Here I am!</small>
</h1>
```

$(document).ready( function() {

```
$('#h1id #something').text('I can change this');
$('#h1id #smallid').text('But not this');
```

});

Answer (score 2):

The `.text()` function replaces all content in the `H1` tag therefore removing the `span` tag from the DOM.

You can append the span with jquery like the following fiddle shows:

http://jsfiddle.net/nkzbzm7f/1/

html

```
<h1 id='h1id'>
    Hello World
</h1>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#h1id').text('I can change this')
    .append("<br>")
    .append("<small>Here I am!</small>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the H1 the small text disappears because it's part of the H1. Adding extra divs or spans isn't nice. keep your html slim!

change h1 text only:

```
$('#h1id').html('new text<br><small>' + $('#h1id small').html() + '</small>' );
```

change small text only:

```
$('#h1id small').text('new text');
```

change both:

```
$('#h1id').html('new test<br><small>new also</small>');
```

Comment: So, if i want to change `<small>` text, how ?

Comment: $('#h1id small').text('mytext');

Comment: and changing h1 text only:
    $('#h1id').html('new text<br><small>' + $('#h1id small').html() + '</small>' );

adding extra spans or divs isn't a great way of doin this. keep your HTML slim!

Comment: Yeah. This one looks better than your answer. `$('#h1id').html('new text<br><small>' + $('#h1id small').html() + '</small>' ); `

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should cache it in a var before replacing the text:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    var smallid = $('#smallid'); // cache it here.
    $('#h1id').text('I can change this. ');
    smallid.text('changed').appendTo('#h1id'); // now change and append it again.

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='h1id'>
    Hello World
    <br>
    <small id='smallid'>Here I am!</small>
</h1>
```